# Проверка результата работы функции

Tags: php, ооп

```
class MyClass
{
    private $_name;
    private $_lastName;

    public function run()
    {   
        $this->_setName();
        $this->_setLastName();
        $this->_getFullName();
    }

    private function _setName()
    {
        $this->_name = 'Вася';
    }

    private function _setLastName()
    {
        if (isset($this->_name))
            $this->_lastName = 'Петров';
    }

    private function _getFullName()
    {
        return $this->_name . $this->_lastName;
    }
}
```

Как в методе Run() перед выполнением getFullName() проверить, что setName() и setLastName() отработали корректно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все зависит от того, что вы понимаете под корректностью. Но можно использовать исключения, см. [php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php), тогда ваш код будет выглядеть так:

```
public function run() {
    $e = FALSE;
    
    try {   
        $this->_setName();
        $this->_setLastName();
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        // Что-то случилось
    }
    if ($e === FALSE) {
        // Тут все OK
        $this->_getFullName();
    }
}
```

Само собой в `_setName` и `_setLastName` если что не так, то делать:

```
throw new Exception('Error message here');
```

Comment: Про Exception знаю, они появились только в PHP5. Как сделать проверку, без использования исключений. Мне хочется понять сам принцип.

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае достаточно проверить поля `$_name` и `$_lastName` на пустоту

Да и, опять таки, представить себе класс с именно такой вот конструкцией довольно таки сложно...

Если б класс был бы "нормальным". т.е. что-то типа:

```
class MyClass
{
    private $_name;
    private $_lastName;

    public function __construct($name, $lastName) {
        // то уже тут можно проверять нормально ли все отработает
        // т.е. что-то типа
        if( is_string($name) && is_string($lastName) ) {
            $this->_setName($name);
            $this->_setLastName($lastName);
        }
        else {
            // что-то не так...
            // в данном случае достаточно такой проверки
        }
    }
    // зачем здесь метод run лично мне непонятно...
    /*
    public function run()
    {   
        $this->_setName();
        $this->_setLastName();
        $this->_getFullName();
    }
    */
    private function _setName($name)
    {
        // ну и тут, например
        // хоть что-нибудь сделаем с именем перед
        // тем как записать его значение
        $name = ucfirst($name); // первую букву в верхний регистр
        $this->_name = $name;
    }

    private function _setLastName($lastName)
    {
        //  if (isset($this->_name))
        //  вот сдесь это уже лишнее
        $lastName = ucfirst($lastName);
        $this->_lastName = $lastName;
    }

    // тоже как-то глупо
    // я же писал что методы которые начинаются с get обычно
    // должны быть публичными...
    // в данном случае - метод 100% должен быть публичным
    private function getFullName()
    {
        // и тут пробел забыл дописать :)
        return $this->_name .' ' . $this->_lastName;
    }
}
//   ну и для примера
$user = new MyClass('Вася', 'Пупкин');
echo $user->getFullName();
```

Теперь поясню почему я переписал класс.. Причина в том что ваш пример не несет абсолютно никакого практического смысла, в твоем примере - мы имеем всего навсего 1 публичный метод который инициализирует поля явными образом, т.е. инициализируются даже не переменные а фиксировные значение.. Конечно я понимаю что пример абстрактный, но тем не менее.. Метод run не может вызвать ошибку по поределению. Поэтому я немного переписал ваш пример.

Опять таки важно понимать - если нельзя(нехотите) использовать исключения - используйте простые ифы...

Если же класс довольно таки большой и в нем может быть много ошибок, то о оних надо как-то узанавать, например можно проинициализировать поле `$_errors` и метод `hasErrors()` который будет считать длину массива `$_errors` и, если она больше 0я, возвращать `true`, ну и публичный метод `getErrors()` который просто возвращает ошибки . Тогда получится что-то типа:

```
$user = new MyClass('', '');
if(!$user->hasErrors()) { //если ошибок нет
    // все идет по плану
}
else {
    // что-то не так...
    $errors = $user->getErrors(); // получаем ошибки
    //  дальше код...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. Пример действительно не удачный.
В моем рабочем классе, public метод run() запускает несколько private методов в определенной последовательности. Если один из private методов вернет ошибку, выполнение кода останавливается. Если использовать Исключения, поймать ошибку и остановить выполнение просто. А вот как сделать без Исключений... 
Инициализировать поле $_errors и в private методах, в случае ошибки делать return $_errors. Но как тогда в public run() отлавливать эти ошибки и останавливать выполнение. Причем не всего скрипта, а только этого класса.